# Spring JPA repository: prevent update on save

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My `user` DB table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    username VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    enabled BOOL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is the field definitions of my entity:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
```

The field `username` is the key of my table/entity and it's up to me to set its value.
When I need to create another user, I do this in my service:

```
public User insertUserImpl(String username, String firstName, String lastName) {
    Assert.hasText(username);
    Assert.hasText(firstName);
    Assert.hasText(lastName);

    String password = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4); // temp
    User user = new User(username, password);
    user.setFirstName(firstName);
    user.setLastName(lastName);
    user.setEnabled(false);
    this.userRepository.save(user);
    // FIXME - assegnare un ruolo
    return user;
}
```

Anyway, if the username is already taken, the repository just do an update, because the specified identifier is not null. This is not the behaviour that I want, I need it to throw something like a duplicate entry exception.
Is there any way to prevent it? Do I have to do it by myself?
E.g.:

```
User user = this.userRepository.findOne(username);
if(user != null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Username already taken"); // FIXME - eccezione applicativa
}
```

Comment: If it is updating the value instead of making a new insertion, it means it thinks it is the same object, but with updated values, are you reusing the object to make several insertions? what flush mode are you using?

Comment: I'm not reusing the same object, I edited the text so you can see the full method. How can I check my flush mode? I think it's the Spring Boot default, I didn't set anything about it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When using the default configuration, and using `CrudRepository#save()` or `JpaRepository#save()` it will delegate to the `EntityManager` to use either `persists()` if it is a new entity, or `merge()` if it is not.

The strategy followed to detect the entity state, new or not, to use the appropiate method, when using the default configuration is as follows:

- By default, a **Property-ID** inspection is performed, if it is `null`, then it is a new entity, otherwise is not.
- If the entity implements `Persistable` the detection will be delegated to the `isNew()` method implemented by the entity.
- There is a 3rd option, implementing `EntityInformation`, but further customizations are needed.

[source](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites)

So in your case, as you are using the username as `ID`, and it isn't null, the Repository call ends up delegating to `EntityManager.merge()` instead of `persist()`. So there are two possible solutions:

- use a diferent `ID` property, set it to null, and use any auto-generation method, or
- make User implement `Persistable` and use the `isNew()` method, to determine if it is a new entity or not.

---

If for some reason, you don't want to modify your entities, you can also change the behaviour modifying the flush mode configuration.  By default, in spring data jpa, hibernate flush mode is set to AUTO.  What you want to do is to change it to COMMIT, and the property to change it is `org.hibernate.flushMode`.  You can modify this configuration by overriding a `EntityManagerFactoryBean` in a `@Configuration` class.

---

And if you don't want to mess the configuration of the EntityManager, you can use the `JpaRepository#flush()` or `JpaRepository#saveAndFlush()` methods, to commit the pending changes to the database.

Comment: Could someone summarize, please, there is some sort of `insert-only` annotation I can put on a `JpaRepository` class to make entity non-updatable? Doesn't `org.hibernate.flushMode` apply to _whole project_?

Answer (score 2):

One can perhaps use existsById(ID primaryKey) to test it, if userRepository extends CrudRepository:

```
if(userRepository.existsById(username)){
    //Throw your Exception
} else {
    this.userRepository.save(user);
}
```

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
    this.userRepository.save(user) 
, can you try 
    this.userRepository.saveAndFlush(user)

My best guess is, it will make your entity detached and as per the JPA documentation, it states an **EntityExistsException is thrown by the persist method when the object passed in is a detached entity. Or any other PersistenceException when the persistence context is flushed or the transaction is committed.**